# Корректно ли говорить «Достал с холодильника»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Сказал подруге: "Я достал монополию с холодильника", и она почему-то подумала, что я взял игру **из** холодильника.
Даже не понял её сначала, но она рьяно мне доказывает, что выражаться так, подразумевая "Достал предмет, лежавший на холодильнике" — некорректно. Утверждает, что её образование переводчика подвести не может и надо говорить "Достал монополию, которая лежала на холодильнике" и никак иначе.
Не понимаю, для чего так усложнять жизнь. Вроде всё верно сказал. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CtsCErgCCrUCEmEKFwoDbGV4EhAKDtC00L7RgdGC0LDRgtGMCgoKBGZvcm0SAgoACgsKBWdyYW1tEgIKAAoJCgNzZW0SAgoAChUKB3NlbS1tb2QSCgoIc2VtfHNlbXgKCwoFZmxhZ3MSAgoAEmMKCwoDbGV4EgQKAtGBCgoKBGZvcm0SAgoACgsKBWdyYW1tEgIKAAoJCgNzZW0SAgoAChUKB3NlbS1tb2QSCgoIc2VtfHNlbXgKCwoFZmxhZ3MSAgoACgwKBGRpc3QiBAgBEAESawoTCgNsZXgSDAoK0L%2FQvtC70LrQsAoKCgRmb3JtEgIKAAoLCgVncmFtbRICCgAKCQoDc2VtEgIKAAoVCgdzZW0tbW9kEgoKCHNlbXxzZW14CgsKBWZsYWdzEgIKAAoMCgRkaXN0IgQIARABKhcKCAgAEAoYMiAKIAAo2MPJ06yPmANABTICCAE6AQEwAQ%3D%3D

Comment: Соглашусь с ней, реально звучит, будто достали из холодильника. Как и с: *достал с телевизора*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнем с глагола ["достать"](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C):
**2.** *что.* Взять что-либо находящееся на расстоянии; извлечь, вынуть откуда-либо. ***Достать книгу с полки.** Достать платок из кармана. Достать свёрток из шкафа. Достать ведро из колодца* (поднять наверх).

Теперь о предлогах:
если действие направлено **изнутри наружу**, употребляется **из**;
если действие направлено **с поверхности чего-либо**, то употребляется предлог **с**. Он выражает пространственное отношение, а именно направление *сверху вниз*.

Так что говорить *достать с холодильника* вполне возможно (при условии, что он выше человека).

Примеры:
*―  Ну, вот,  ― Фарид торжественно поднялся на ноги, постоял, моргая, затем **достал с холодильника** топографическую карту, сложенную какой-то серединной восьмушкой наружу* (О. А. Славникова. 2017);
*Кузьма поднялся и **достал со шкафа** банку с деньгами* (В. Г. Распутин. Деньги для Марии);
*― Следователь, торжествующе играя густыми бровями и морщинами на лбу, **достал с этажерки** старенький портфель* (В. Я. Шишков. Угрюм-река).

Comment: Но сейчас часто вместо "из" употребляют "с", поэтому звучит двусмысленно.

Comment: Думается, Вы что-то путаете про частотность. В НКРЯ: "достал **с** холодильника" — 1; "достал **из** холодильника" — 53 (https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=ClUKKtC00L7RgdGC0LDQuyDQuNC3INGF0L7Qu9C%2B0LTQuNC70YzQvdC40LrQsCogCggIABAKGDIgCiAAKJKqqra3vNACQAVKB2NyZWF0ZWQyAggBOgEBMAE%3D).

Comment: Имею в виду то, как люди говорят, а не навязчивые нормы, которых стараются придерживаться авторы, чтобы не было вопросов.

Answer (score -1):

Скажите ей, что она душная. Все так говорят и будут говорить. Думаю, в будущем "из" останется только там, где его удобно произносить (например, в составе союза "из-за").

Comment: Из крана льется вода, человек вышел из подъезда, получаю знания из книг... Никто (нормальный) не заменит здесь предлог "из" на "с". Кстати, "из-за" — это тоже предлог, не союз.

Comment: обязательно заменят, как это и произошло в большинстве славянских языков